# How to maintain more than one view root in single browser tab?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra

We have developed a web application using JSF. This application contains multiple screens which are rendered inside tab (using jquery). When user clicks on a menuitem, we will include a xhtml belongs to that menu and it will be rendered inside a tab. On analysing application performance we found that, more time was spent on restore view phase of JSF when the number of opened screens gets increased(ie., when more components are added to same viewroot, restore view can consume time).

I need solution for the below mentioned questions:

1. How to reduce the time taken in restore view?
2. Is it possible to change the view state id for form inside every jquery tab? This can reduce the number of components in view root which inturn reduces the time spent in restore view by having separate viewroot for each tab. Is this workaround is possible?

Environment:
Server : wildfly10.0
Jsf implementation : mojarra-2.2.

Comment: tried iframes? And Myfaces has viewcaching. might be interesting too. I hope it makes it into Mojarra too in jsf 2.4

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. We are having common js and css files and also primefaces resources. If we use iframe means all resources will be loaded separately for each iframe. This may cause performance issues in browser side. Is it possible to make iframe to use js loaded by the main page?

Comment: No, that would defeat the whole purpose of an iframe... being isolated... Just make sure the caching is done correctly and there will not be a performance problem.